# qgis2web incorrect leaflet popup position

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I have encountered some problems with positions of popup containing image in leaflet format (version) of this great tool. Sometimes has the pointer of popup (in a picture marked with red circle) incorrect (to the right moved) position. Is it easy to fix it? In an extreme case could help remove pointer from popup. Is it possible? qgis2web 2.34.0, QGIS 2.14.2-2[image: moved position of pointer]

Comment: Your QGIS and Qgis2Web versions are quite old.  Are you able to update to the latest versions?

Comment: I bought a new computer last week, upgraded to QGIS3 (3.4.8) with a latest gis2web plugin. And the situation is even more problematic, There is no transparency of vector layers and the a bug https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19118.

Comment: You can modify the transparency by editing the resulting web map.  If you are using OpenLayers, change the code in the styles folder fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(145,36,218,0.5)'}),

Comment: If you are using Leaflet then find fillOpacity in index.html and change it to your preference.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the transparency is fixed. But I encounter still the same problem with the uncorrect position of popup pointer (it is moved to the left on the web map (position in preview was ok).